# $ Not Defined Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code is for creating checkbox dynamically.

But in Chrome console it says $ is not defined. This $ error is in this line:

```
$.post(
            "index1.php", 
            { 
                "newopt": newopt  
            },
```

**Full Code here...**

```
var optiondiv = document.getElementById('option-div');

document.getElementById('create').onclick = function () {

    newopt = document.getElementById('new-option').value;
    if(newopt){
        var input = document.createElement('input'),
        label = document.createElement('label');
         /* IF USER DID NOT INPUT A TEXT, 'No Entered Text' WILL BE THE DEFAULT VALUE */
    newopt = (newopt == '')?'No Entered Text':newopt;
      /* FILL OUT THE TAGS OF THE NEW INPUT ELEMENT */
        input.type = "checkbox";
        input.setAttribute("value", newopt);
        input.setAttribute("checked", true);
        input.setAttribute("name", "prints[]");
        /* PUT THE INPUT ELEMENT/RADIO BUTTON INSIDE THE LABEL */
        label.appendChild(input);
        label.innerHTML += newopt+'<br>'; 
         /* PUT THE LABEL ELEMENT INSIDE THE option-div DIV */
        optiondiv.appendChild(label);
        //optiondiv.appendChild(input);
        //ele.appendChild(input);
        //input.onclick = function(){ alert('this is test'); };

        //optiondiv.appendChild(label);
        document.getElementById('new-option').value = '';

        $.post(
            "index1.php", 
            { 
                "newopt": newopt  
            }, 
            function(data) {
                if(data.success){
                    alert('Successfully Added To dB');
                }else{
                    alert('Not Added To DB');
                }

        });

    }else{
        alert('Please Enter Check Box Value.');
        return false;
    }



};
```

Comment: And this question is tagged with "PHP" because of... ?

Comment: That's not php but javascript and jQuery. Have you included jQuery?

Comment: have you tried replacing `$` with `jQuery` ?

Comment: Import jQuery in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To use jQuery in your own JavaScript you need to ensure the `<script>` element that includes jQuery *before* your own JavaScript (whether inline or included).

(Strictly speaking, be delaying execution you can be less strict, but start with the simple approach.)

Eg. this will work:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type='text/JavaScript'>
  // Your code using jQUery
</script>
```

but this will not:

```
<script type='text/JavaScript'>
  // Your code using jQUery
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
```